# How to capture image from a streaming video of ip camera that shown in video view in android

Tags: android, video-streaming, ip-camera, android-videoview

I want to ask how to capture image from a streaming video of an ip camera that shown in my app through video view layout in my app, when i click a button it will capture the image that shown in video view. i use a rtsp protocol ip camera..

```
package com.javacodegeeks.androidvideoviewexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class AndroidVideoViewExample extends Activity {

    private VideoView myVideoView;
    private int position = 0;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private MediaController mediaControls;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the layout from video_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (mediaControls == null) {
            mediaControls = new MediaController(AndroidVideoViewExample.this);
        }

        // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
        myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);

        // Create a progressbar
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(AndroidVideoViewExample.this);
        // Set progressbar title
        progressDialog.setTitle("JavaCodeGeeks Android Video View Example");
        // Set progressbar message
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // Show progressbar
        progressDialog.show();

        try {

            myVideoView.setMediaController(mediaControls);
            myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://192.168.2.12/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                myVideoView.seekTo(position);
                if (position == 0) {
                    myVideoView.start();
                } else {
                    myVideoView.pause();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("Position", myVideoView.getCurrentPosition());
        myVideoView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        position = savedInstanceState.getInt("Position");
        myVideoView.seekTo(position);
    }
}
```

this is the coding that I found in this group, it work awesomely...now I want to add a button to capture the image,

what I have found that we can use mediadataretriever method and save it to sd card?
is that true?

Comment: You can take a screenshot programmatically and crop it and save it to the card

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Shink, I would like to reserve it as last play card, do you have any method to do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to capture image also in a bit another way using cgi service for example available with dahua IPC-HDW2231T-AS-S2.

```
http://CAM-IP/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi
```

In my case I use it to invoke snapshot creation and automatically store it on ftp server, but if you want get image from request the rule will be the same.

To make that request without getting a 401 - unathorized result code you have to implement **digest authentication**. You can make it on your way or use like me the [bare-bones-digest](https://github.com/al-broco/bare-bones-digest) dependency.

Then you can make AsyncTask class to make it asynchronous (below example in kotlin)

```kotlin
class RequestTask :
        AsyncTask<String?, String?, Boolean?>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): Boolean? {            
            // Step 1. Create the connection
            val url = URL(params[0])
            var connection =
                url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

            // Step 2. Make the request and check to see if the response contains an authorization challenge
            if (connection.responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                // Step 3. Create a authentication object from the challenge...
                val auth: DigestAuthentication = DigestAuthentication.fromResponse(connection)
                // ...with correct credentials
                auth.username(username).password(password)

                // Step 4 (Optional). Check if the challenge was a digest challenge of a supported type
                if (!auth.canRespond()) {
                    // No digest challenge or a challenge of an unsupported type - do something else or fail
                    return false
                }

                // Step 5. Create a new connection, identical to the original one...
                connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                // ...and set the Authorization header on the request, with the challenge response
                connection.setRequestProperty(
                    DigestChallengeResponse.HTTP_HEADER_AUTHORIZATION,
                    auth.getAuthorizationForRequest("GET", connection.url.path)
                )
            }

            connection.connect() //there you can also get inputStream from connection for local store of snapshot
            val responseCode = connection.responseCode
            val cLength = connection.contentLength         
            return responseCode == 200
        }
    }
```

and to execute use:

```kotlin
RequestTask().execute("http://$CAM-IP/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi")
```

If you encounter the `Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted` error then see [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted) for help.